# Looking help regarding SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization

I am looking for a better way of retrieving data from my sql tables.

```
Table 1: User data
- User Id
- User Created date

Table 2: Mapping of the user with a role
- User Id
- Role

Table 3 
Role definition

Table 4 (may or may not have user data based on his activities on the site)
User data
Eg.
- User Id
- Total counts of the number of visits made on the portal
```

I am looking to write least amount of queries(preferably 1) to do the following

**I want to print the top users for each of the role types who have highest total count **

The output would read something like the following:

```
Header UserId---Rolename--Total Count
Row1   Test1 ---Staff   --1293
Row2   Test2 ---Faculty --1223
Row3   Test3 ---Dean    --2283928
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider providing DDLs (and/or a SQLFIDDLE) illustrating the above together with a representative data set and desired result set.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
SELECT a.UserId, b.Role, c.TotalCount
FROM TABLE1 as a join Table2 as b on a.UserId = b.UserId
                 join Table 4 as c on a.UserId = c.UserId
ORDER BY c.TotalCount DESC
LIMIT 3
```